# Node.js fs.appendFile if string doesn't exist in the text file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Please looking for suggestions for the best way to append to a text file if the line in the text file does not exist?

For example, file.txt looks like this:

```
Aimee Kestenberg
ALLSAINTS
14th & Union
3.1 PHILLIP LIM
Champion
Botkier
CHRISTIAN LAURIER
Christopher Kon
Co-Lab
Day & Mood
```

For example if var x = "Aimee Kestenberg"
Need to add x to file.txt if x does not exist.

The text file would not be too big, around 100-200 lines at most as it grows.
Would I need to read the text file into an array and split on new line?
Then loop through the array and check if it is equal to x?
Then fs.appendFile if x is not in the array?

Currently I'm using fs.appendFile to add all x to the text file.
But the goal is to only add x if it doesn't already exist in the text file.

```
fs.appendFile('file.txt', '\n' + x, (err) => {
   if (err) throw err;
});
```

Can anyone please help what the code would look like for reading in the text file and looping through it?  Or is there a better way of doing this will built in functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method returns a `Promise` that will tell whether a file contains a given line. Note that it is case sensitive.

```
import { readFile } from "fs/promises";

const containsLine = (path, line) =>
  new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const data = await readFile(path);
    const lines = data.toString().split(/\r?\n/);
    resolve(lines.includes(line));
});
```

You can then wrap your own code like this to have a generic asynchronous function:

```
import { appendFile } from "fs/promises";

async function appendLineIfLacking(path, line) {
  if (await containsLine(path, line))
    await appendFile(path, "\n" + line );
}
```

Comment: Why not just search the text as is (taking `\n` into account with regex) instead of all that splitting and searching just to check the line exists

Comment: If I understand you correctly that would mean you'd have to construct a regular expression of the `line` input followed by `((\r?\n)|$)` to account for different operating systems having different line breaks or the end of the file. Because `line` will be inserted into a regular expression it needs to be escaped as well. That, or the approach above using a split function and then a linear search which also reads nicely because it documents its functionality perfectly.

Comment: @Tibebes.M If you have other reasons to prefer your approach I'm curious as to what those are. Performance wise the OP has stated that the file contains 100-200 lines, so in that domain I would consider it an over-optimization sacrificing readability. If the dataset would've been big enough to matter, I would switch to streaming the file instead anyhow.

Comment: As obvious as it is, the need for escaping didn't cross my mind for some reason apparently.. You're correct. My suggestion can easily become buggy

Comment: If you want to use promises and async/await, rather than manually wrapping with a promise, you can `import { promises as fs } from 'fs'`, and use `const { readFile, appendFile } = fs`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have updated the snippets accordingly.

Comment: Can there be a race condition? Let's say we use that code in express and 2 requests trigger it to append the same line. I guess containsLine could return false for both requests resulting in both requests appending the line?!

Answer (score 1):

Your idea on iterating through the lines is a good one. You could also skip the splitting and iteration and check through the whole file:

```
const inputData = fs.readfileSync('file.txt').toString()

itemsToAppend.forEach((item) => {
  const line = `${item}\n`
  if (!inputData.includes(line)) {
    fs.appendFile('file.txt', line, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
    })
  }
})
```

You could also get unique lines and then re-write the whole file (I'm using the `sync` methods here for brevity but the async versions would work too):

```
const inputData = fs.readfileSync('file.txt').toString().split('\n')
const newFile = [...new Set([...myNewLines, ...inputData])].join('\n')
fs.writeFileSync('file.txt', newFile)
```